# onPress not firing on Android but fine on iOS

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I've written a React Native app, iOS was the priority so I built that first. It's in the App Store and works perfectly, however I've just started working on Android and although everything *appears* to be working correctly except for touch events, which are not firing at all.

None of the touchable elements are calling the `onPress` callback, nor is the `Button` element. I've even tried stripping the app down completely, removing the navigator, and adding a load of touchable elements to the initial screen but still none of the `onPress` callbacks are firing.

Below is the code for the initial screen of my app, though I doubt any of this code is causing the issue:

```
// @flow
import React, { type Element } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import type { NavigatorScreenProps } from 'react-navigation';
import i18n from '../../i18n';
import style from './style';

type Props = {
  navigation: NavigatorScreenProps
}

export default function SignIn ({ navigation }: Props): Element<typeof View> {
  return (
    <View style={style.container}>
      <View style={style.top}>
        <Image source={require('../../assets/images/purpleWithTransparentBackground.png')} style={style.logo} />
      </View>
      <View style={style.bottom}>
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.97} onPressIn={() => console.log('in')} onPressOut={() => console.log('out')} onPress={() => { console.log('do something!'); navigation.navigate('EnterEmail'); }} style={[style.submit, { zIndex: 99999, elevation: 99999 }]}>
          <Text style={style.submitText}>
            {i18n.t('SIGN_IN')}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <Image source={require('../../assets/images/cityscapeGrey.png')} style={style.cityscape} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Component styles:

```
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import defaultStyles from '../../style';

const { width: screenWidth } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: defaultStyles.white
  },

  top: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%'
  },

  bottom: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%'
  },

  animatedContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: '100%'
  },

  postcode: {
    padding: 12,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: '100%',
    borderRadius: 5,
    fontSize: 17
  },

  text: {
    width: 296,
    height: 44,
    fontFamily: 'SFProText-Light',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '500',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    lineHeight: 22,
    letterSpacing: 0,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: defaultStyles.balticSea
  },

  logo: {
    marginBottom: 14
  },

  error: {
    color: defaultStyles.brickRed,
    marginVertical: 12,
    width: '100%',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },

  submit: {
    width: 311,
    height: 56,
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: defaultStyles.mountainMeadow,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: 30
  },

  submitText: {
    width: 311,
    height: 21,
    fontFamily: 'SFProDisplay-Heavy',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    letterSpacing: 0,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: defaultStyles.white
  },

  highlight: {
    color: defaultStyles.mountainMeadow
  },

  cityscape: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    width: screenWidth,
    resizeMode: 'repeat'
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: just an idea, did you try to remove the `activeOpacity={0.97}` ?

Comment: @oma I've tried using different touchable elements with no custom opacity, still no luck unfortunately!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem.

Short answer:

I have a component in the root of my app that was creating an invisible overlay. This happened because `display: 'none'` and `position: 'absolute'` don't work if applied to the same element on Android.

Long answer:

In my root component I have a menu that comes up from the bottom of the screen called `OptionsMenu`:

```
export default function App (): Element<typeof Provider> {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ActionSheetProvider>
        <OptionsMenuContext.Provider>
          <>
            <Navigation uriPrefix={DEEP_LINK_URI_PREFIX} ref={setNavigator} />
            <Notification />
            <OptionsMenu />
          </>
        </OptionsMenuContext.Provider>
      </ActionSheetProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Inside `OptionsMenu` there is an overlay that covers the screen, this is so we can dim everything when the menu appears. The overlay (the outermost `Animated.View`) has `position: 'absolute'` as well as `display: 'none'`. The `display` setting comes from a prop and the `position` comes from `style.container`:

```
function OptionsMenu ({ hideOptionsMenu, overlayDisplay, overlayOpacity, containerPositionBottom, options = [] }: Props): Element<typeof Animated.View> {
  return (
    <Animated.View style={[style.container, { display: overlayDisplay }]}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={hideOptionsMenu}>
        <Animated.View style={[style.overlay, { opacity: overlayOpacity }]} />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <Animated.View style={[style.optionsContainer, { bottom: containerPositionBottom }]}>
        {options.map(({ icon, text, onPress, type, component: Component }: Option) => !Component
          ? (
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.97} key={text} disabled={!onPress} onPress={onPress} style={style.optionContainer}>
              {!!icon && (
                <Image source={icon} style={[style.optionIcon, optionTypeTintMap[type]]} />
              )}
              <Text style={[style.optionText, optionTypeColorMap[type || 'neutralColor']]}>
                {text}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ) : (
            <Component key={text} />
          ))}
      </Animated.View>
    </Animated.View>
  );
}

export default withOptionsContext(OptionsMenu);
```

The problem was that on Android the absolute positioning will override the display setting. So the solution was to wrap an absolute positioned component inside a component which controlled the display setting:

OptionsMenu/style.js:

```
export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    // Removed these:
    // position: 'absolute',
    // left: 0,
    // bottom: 0,
    // width: screenWidth,
    // height: screenHeight,
    // zIndex: 19,
    // elevation: 19
  },

  // Moved styles to new property:
  overlayContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    width: screenWidth,
    height: screenHeight,
    zIndex: 19,
    elevation: 19
  },
```

OptionsMenu/OptionsMenu.js:

```
function OptionsMenu ({ hideOptionsMenu, overlayDisplay, overlayOpacity, containerPositionBottom, options = [] }: Props): Element<typeof Animated.View> {
  return (
    // Added new <View /> to control display setting separately:
    <View style={[style.container, { display: overlayDisplay }]}>
      <Animated.View style={style.overlayContainer}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give **height** and **width** to **TouchableOpacity**

```
            <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.97} 
                onPressIn={() => console.log('in')} 
                onPressOut={() => console.log('out')} 
                onPress={() => { console.log('do something!'); navigation.navigate('EnterEmail'); }} 
                style={[style.submit, { zIndex: 99999, elevation: 99999, height:200, width:200 }]}>
                <Text style={style.submitText}>
                    {i18n.t('SIGN_IN')}
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

I just added **200** for both for testing.

Working code from Android:

`<View style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'red'
            }}>
                <View style={style.container}>
                    <View style={style.top}>
                    </View>
                    <View style={style.bottom}>
                        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.97} onPressIn={() => alert('in')} onPressOut={() => alert('out')} onPress={() => { alert('do something!'); }} style={[style.submit, { zIndex: 99999, elevation: 99999 }]}>
                            <Text style={style.submitText}>
                                GENERAL TEXT
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>`

Comment: `style.submit` has height and width

Comment: Can you send style of submit?